# How to get second unique date from array object

Tags: javascript

How to find second unique date using JS, e.g. output should return **2019-12-25T02:34:00Z**

```
const data = [
  { date: '2019-12-24T03:24:00Z' },
  { date: '2019-12-24T04:56:00Z' },
  { date: '2019-12-25T02:34:00Z' },
  { date: '2019-12-26T01:23:00Z' }
]
```

Using the following code, I was able to return a second unique date

```
const data = [
    { date: "2019-12-24T03:24:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-24T04:56:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-26T01:23:00Z" }
  ];

  const uniqueDateStrings = [
    ...new Set(data.map((item) => item.date.slice(0, 10)))
  ];

  if (uniqueDateStrings.length >= 2) {
    const secondUniqueDate = uniqueDateStrings[1];
    const secondUniqueFullDate = data.find((item) =>
      item.date.startsWith(secondUniqueDate)
    );
    console.log(secondUniqueFullDate.date);
  } else {
    console.log("There are not enough unique dates.");
  }
```

Would you be able to provide an optimized version of this code?

Comment: All four dates are unique. So, the second relative to what? The first item in the list? That would be`'2019-12-24T04:56:00Z'`.

Comment: Please read how to ask questions on SO?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  I think he just means the date part eg.  `2019-12-25`, Javascript `Date`, really should be called a DateTime.. :)

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it seems to be an interesting question, and has good answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the second different date:

```js
const data = [
{ date: "2019-12-24T03:24:00Z" },
{ date: "2019-12-24T04:56:00Z" },
{ date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
{ date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
{ date: "2019-12-26T01:23:00Z" }
  ];

let prev;
const result = data.find(({date: item}) => {
  const date = item.slice(0, 10);
  if(prev && prev !== date) return true;
  prev = date;
})?.date;


console.log(result || "There are not enough unique dates.");
```

Comment: it will not work for following array 
const data = [
    { date: "2019-12-24T03:24:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-24T04:56:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
    { date: "2019-12-26T01:23:00Z" }
  ];

Answer (score 1):

The `uniqueByKey` function below will store a reference to and index of the each item it encounters with a unique date:

```js
const data = [
  { date: "2019-12-24T03:24:00Z" },
  { date: "2019-12-24T04:56:00Z" },
  { date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
  { date: "2019-12-25T02:34:00Z" },
  { date: "2019-12-26T01:23:00Z" }
];

const uniqueByKey = (arr, keyFn) =>
  [...arr.reduce((lookup, reference, index) =>
    (key => !lookup.has(key) ?
      lookup.set(key, { index, reference }) : lookup)
    (keyFn(reference)), new Map).values()]; 

const uniqueRefs = uniqueByKey(data, ({ date }) => date.slice(0, 10));

{
  const { reference: ref, index } = uniqueRefs[1];
  console.log(`2nd unique item :- index=${index} | value='${ref.date}'`);
  console.log('Are the same?', data[index] === ref);
}

{
  const { reference: ref, index } = uniqueRefs[2];
  console.log(`3nd unique item :- index=${index} | value='${ref.date}'`);
  console.log('Are the same?', data[index] === ref);
}
```

Output:

```
2nd unique item :- index=2 | value='2019-12-25T02:34:00Z'
Are the same? true

3nd unique item :- index=4 | value='2019-12-26T01:23:00Z'
Are the same? true
```

The index could be used to index on the original `data` array, or the `reference` could be used; your choice.

---

If the function above is too terse, here is the expanded form:

```js
function uniqueByKey(arr, keyFn) {
  const lookup = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const key = keyFn(arr[i]);
    if (lookup.has(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    lookup.set(key, {
      index: i,
      reference: arr[i]
    });
  }
  return Array.from(lookup.values());
}
```

Comment: i wonder why converstion to dates is needed since the data is in fixed format. using iterators and intermediate arrays should worsen the speed more

Comment: anyway, the output isn't what the OP requested, why 2019-12-24 since there're two dates

Comment: 2019-12-24 isn't a unique date in the array

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I update my algorithm to account for OPs intended behavior.

Comment: Added a non-terse version.

Comment: seems a bad solution, there's no need to analyze a whole array, just find the second unique date, seems a very simple task, check my answer